# if $\vDash \alpha \ \Rightarrow \ \vDash \beta$ then $\vDash \alpha \to \beta$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

if $\vDash \alpha \ \Rightarrow \  \vDash \beta$ then $\vDash \alpha  \to \beta$ ?

Is this proposition true? And what about converse?  I also wonder about the difference between $\Rightarrow$ and $\to$ in this proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\to$ is the *propositional connective* ["if..., then..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional). It is part of the language of propositional logic and it is used (with other connectives) to symbolize the formulas of the formal system.

The symbol $\vDash \alpha$ is not part of the language of the system but is part of the meta-language : it asserts the fact that formula $\alpha$ is a *tautology* (or *logically valid*).

Thus, $\Rightarrow$ is used in te meta-language to abbreviate "if..., then..." when expressing properties of the formal system.

---

Regarding the question :

> if $⊨ α \ ⇒ \ ⊨ β$, then $⊨ α → β$ ?

the answer is no.

Consider the atom $p$ as $\alpha$ and the atom $q$ as $\beta$.

We have that $\vDash p$ is $\text {False}$.

Thus :

> $\vDash p \ \Rightarrow \ \vDash q$ holds,

because $\text {False } \Rightarrow \text { False}$ is $\text {True}$.

But $\nvDash (p \to q)$, because $p \to q$ is not a *tautology*.

---

About the converse : assume that $\vDash \alpha \to \beta$ and $\vDash \alpha$.

We reason by contradiction, i.e. assume that $\nvDash \beta$. This means that for some truth assignment $v$ we have $v(\beta)=$ **f**.

But from $\vDash \alpha$, we have that $v(\alpha)=$ **t**.

Thus :

> $v(\alpha \to \beta)=$ **f**,

contradicting $\vDash \alpha \to \beta$.

Comment: Thank you very much! What about "if $ \vDash \alpha \to \beta $ then $ \vDash \alpha \ \Rightarrow \ \vDash \beta $?" I think this is true, but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Aha! Thank you!  But I have another question. The meaning of $ \Rightarrow $ is the same as the $ \to $ in propositional logic?? For example, if $\alpha$ is true and $\beta$ is false then $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta $ is  false,  if $\alpha$ is  false and $\beta$ is false then $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta $ is  false ... and so on?

Comment: @amoogae - The meaning of ⇒ is the same as the → in propositional logic? YES, but then if α is false and β is false then α⇒β is **true**.

Comment: Oh my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, this story sounds to me as saying "the meta language of propositional logic is propositional logic". Can I understand it this way?

Comment: @amoogae - not excatly... propositional logic is a formalization of our "natural" logic used in reasoning, and specifically in mathematical reasoning. Meta-mathematics is simply a branch of mathematics (the theory of "formal systems") and thus it uses all the tools of mathematical reasoning :-)

Comment: Aha.  Then we use the symbols of meta-language sometimes (like $\Rightarrow$). But we do not formalize the meta-language.  Thank you for your kind answer.